# GET action with multiple ids inputted .NET

Tags: c#, .net, get

It`s possible to create a GET action based on multiple id's inputted?

**For example how can I change this method to be GetCustomer([FromRoute] int id, int code_id)?**

```
// GET: api/Customer/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomer([FromRoute] int id)
    {
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         return BadRequest(ModelState);
      }

      var customerMaster = await _context.CustomerMaster.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Code == id);

      if (customerMaster == null)
      {
         return NotFound();
      }

      return Ok(customerMaster);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible for a method to have more than one argument.  The additional GET parameters would either be in the route or in the query string.

Comment: I just wonder what is wrong in my question for -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AttributeRouting:

```
// GET: api/Customer/5/3

[Route("api/Customer/{id}/{code_id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomer(int id, int code_id)
{

        ...
   return Ok(customer);
}
```

Comment: And how can I concatenate them here: (m => m.Code == id)? with a simple &&?

Comment: Yes, you can use &&, i.e. (m => m.Code == code_id && m.Id == id)

Comment: And how should I do in case i don`t want to return me just he first which is /1/2 and I want to return me all the values which have /1/2?

Comment: use `.ToList()` and return list, instead of a single object, i.e. `List<Customer> customers = context.Customers.Where(m => m.Code == code_id && m.Id == id).toList();`